# Creating an immutable collection structure from existing hierarchical structure

Tags: c#, immutability, readonly-collection

I have an object that stores hierarchical data. I have successfully been able to create the structure I need from a flat structure, but this required me to use `List<>` which isn't immutable (I want to use `IReadOnlyList`).

Now I can't really get my head around how I would create immutable lists based on these children lists. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

The class looks like this:

```
public class ItemOrFolder
{
    public string Id { get; }

    public string Name { get; }

    public List<ItemOrFolder> Children { get; set; }    // Need to create immutable versions of these recursively

    private ItemOrFolder(string id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    public static ItemOrFolder Create(string id, string name)
    {
        return new ItemOrFolder(id, name);
    }
}
```

If `Children` is `null`, then it's an item, otherwise it's a folder, containing zero or more `ItemOrFolder`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find where Children property is set but you just need to add `.ToImmutableList()` to your list

```
item.Children = yourList.ToImmutableList();
```